# UnityWebRequest returns different errors for right urls

Tags: unity-game-engine, request, response, assetbundle, unitywebrequest

I'm using UnityWebRequest to download asset bundles from my server. Sometimes the following code returns different exceptions such as `Failed to receive data` , `Cannot resolve destination host`, `Cannot connect to destination host`, `Unknown Error`, `Request timeout`  and so on.

Here is the part of my code.

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(url,(uint)data.version,0);

                    Debug.Log ("Downloading " + url);
                    
                    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
                    AssetBundle bundle = null;
                    if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
                        Debug.Log(www.isNetworkError);
                        Debug.Log(www.isHttpError);
                        Debug.Log(www.error);

                        if (ARSceneManager.Instance != null)
                            data.downloadAssetBundlesCompleted?.Invoke(null);
                    } else {
                        bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(www);
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error)) {

                        throw new Exception("WWW download: " + url + ", " + www.error);
                    }
```

So I get the errors for different urls and in some cases.

P.S. the same URL works for the next time, also it works in browser too. So I don't think there are issues with urls.

Thanks.